# SSRS Subscription : CSV file delivered to Network share is 0 kb

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS data driven subscription configured to deliver CSV file to network share . The subscription gets processed successfully but the report file delivered to network share shows as 0 kb. The report does render data when the SSRS report is run manually with the same set of parameters used for the subscription and I am able to export to CSV file which has data . If anyone can help me how to troubleshoot this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you check SSRS logs? Maybe you can find some clue. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.Instance\Reporting Services\LogFiles.

Comment: I checked SSRS logs which show as low disk space on Report server. Would this cause an issue for SSRS subscription to deliver CSV to network share ?

Comment: What kind of authentication does the report data source use? Bear in mind that when the report subscription runs, it is as a different domain user to when you run it interactively using your own account. If the report data source uses Windows authentication, possibly the report returns no data when run as a subscription.

Comment: If the .CSV is large enough and the Space is low enough then yes that can cause issues with the CSV file.